# iPhone UIToolbar UIButtonItem highlighting

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar

I have subclassed `UIToolbar` and within it have created a set of `UIButtonItems`, all added in order and nicely spaced with flexible spaces.  I now want to toggle one of the `UIButtonItems` each time it is tapped (just like the shuffle button in iPod, white blue white blue.  I have maintained a reference to the `UIButtonItem`.

```
// interface
UIButtonItem *_shuffleButton;      // released in dealloc

// implementation
UIImage *_shuffleButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shuffle_icon_200x100.png"];
_shuffleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:_shuffleButtonImage  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(shuffleButtonTapped)];
```

So now in `shuffleButtonTapped` I want to do something like:

```
_shuffleButton.highlighted = YES;
// or 
_shuffleButton.selected = YES;
```

but neither of these work.

I have searched high and low and after failing to find anything I am starting to think I am missing something, can anyone tell me what it might be??  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to create my own `navigationItem` Button which is in fact a view and can be animated just like any other view.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30.0);
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.3f green:0.3f blue:0.3f alpha:1.0f]];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:viewController action:@selector(rightButtonTouchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to show wome simple images as a buttons, use UITabBar instead. It will make selection UI changes automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I want the blue appearance of the image I don't want the faded square that surrounds a selected tab. I am fairly sure you cannot have one without the other in a Tabbar. Like I said the effect I am after is the same as the shuffle button in the iPod app, where the image turns blue.  I think I might have to roll my own, unless anyone else has any insights.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try initWithCustomView method of UIBarButtonItem and then change this view after clicking the button